# The way to disable or enable Chrome extension conditionally from the code when using all_urls

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

Previously I was using `matches` in `manifest.json` to whitelist the domains I wanted my extension to work on.

But now I need to enable the extension on all domains and have a possibility to enable disable extension from JavaScript conditionally. So I'm setting `"matches": ["<all_urls>"],` in `manifest.json`. But how do I disable the app conditionally? So the icon on toolbox is greyed out. Is it even possible?

Comment: You can use a gray icon by default and call chrome.browserAction.setIcon to set a color icon for the specified tab id. Another possibility is chrome.declarativeContent.

Answer (score 3):

To listen for url changes, you can hook into tab updates via the `chrome.tabs` api. Then you can disable the icon click by setting the popup to an empty string and the icon to something that looks disabled.

eg.

**Tab urls require the `tabs` permission**

```
// manifest.json

{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
  ...
}
```

**Toggle your extension conditionally**

```
// background.js

const icons = {
  enabled: "/logo32.png",
  disabled: "/logo32-offline.png"
};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (isWhitelisted(tab.url)) {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ tabId, path: icons.enabled });
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "index.html" }); // your popup filename
  } else {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ tabId, path: icons.disabled });
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "" });
  };
});
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs